# How can I test a React Service that fetchs from a backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm checking the test coverage and I'm not currently passing the fetch line (line 3). How can I test the fetch function?

**Service:**

```
export const taskManagerRemoteService = {
  getTasks: (): Promise<any> => {
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}${process.env.REACT_APP_TASKS_URI}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Test:**

```
import "@testing-library/react"
import { taskManagerRemoteService } from "./task-manager.remote.service";

describe("TaskManagerRemoteService", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  it('should get tasks when getTasks method is called', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(taskManagerRemoteService, 'getTasks').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([{}]))
    const tasks = await taskManagerRemoteService.getTasks();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(tasks).toStrictEqual([{}])
  
    spy.mockReset();
    spy.mockRestore();
  })
})
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are testing the `taskManagerRemoteService.getTasks` method, so you should not mock it. You should mock the `fetch` function and its resolved/rejected value.

There are two ways to mock an API request:

1. [msw](https://mswjs.io/) - Mock by intercepting requests on the network level. This way you have to install additional packages and set them up. It does not need to mock and uses the original `fetch` method, which is closer to the real runtime environment.
2. `global.fetch = jest.fn()` - Just mock the `fetch` function, don't need to install any package. But the potentially at risk is incorrect mocks change the `fetch`'s behavior, the test passes, actual code fails.

Below is code using the second way:

`task-manager.remote.service.ts`:

```
export const taskManagerRemoteService = {
  getTasks: (): Promise<any> => {
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}${process.env.REACT_APP_TASKS_URI}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  },
};
```

`task-manager.remote.service.test.ts`:

```
import '@testing-library/react';
import { taskManagerRemoteService } from './task-manager.remote.service';

describe('TaskManagerRemoteService', () => {
  let oFetch: typeof global.fetch;
  beforeAll(() => {
    oFetch = global.fetch;
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    global.fetch = oFetch;
  });
  it('should get tasks when getTasks method is called', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([{}]);
    const tasks = await taskManagerRemoteService.getTasks();

    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(tasks).toStrictEqual([{}]);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71400354/task-manager.remote.service.test.ts
  TaskManagerRemoteService
    ✓ should get tasks when getTasks method is called (5 ms)

--------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 task-manager.remote.service.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.83 s, estimated 2 s
```